# How to call a postback in ASP.Net with Python

Tags: python, asp.net, web-services, http, http-headers

I am trying to web-scrape some elements and their values off a page with **Python**; However, to get more elements, I need to simulate a click on the *next button*. There is a post back tied to these buttons, so I am trying to call it. Unfortunately, Python is only printing the same values over and over again [meaning the post back for the *next button* isn't being called]. I am using `requests` to do my POST/GET.

```
import re
import time
import requests

TARGET_GROUP_ID = 778092


SESSION = requests.Session()
REQUEST_HEADERS = {"Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate"}
GROUP_URL = "http://roblox.com/groups/group.aspx?gid=%d"%(TARGET_GROUP_ID)
POST_BUTTON_HTML = 'pagerbtns next'

EVENTVALIDATION_REGEX = re.compile(r'id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.+)"').search
VIEWSTATE_REGEX = re.compile(r'id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.+)"').search
VIEWSTATEGENERATOR_REGEX = re.compile(r'id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="(.+)"').search
TITLE_REGEX = re.compile(r'<a id="ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxGroupRoleSetMembersPane_dlUsers_ctrl\d+_hlAvatar".*?title="(\w+)".*?ID=(\d+)"')
page = SESSION.get(GROUP_URL, headers = REQUEST_HEADERS).text
while 1:
    if POST_BUTTON_HTML in page:
        for (ids,names) in re.findall(TITLE_REGEX, page):
            print ids,names
        postData = {
            "__EVENTVALIDATION": EVENTVALIDATION_REGEX(page).group(1),
            "__VIEWSTATE": VIEWSTATE_REGEX(page).group(1),
            "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": VIEWSTATEGENERATOR_REGEX(page).group(1),
            "__ASYNCPOST": True,
            "ct1000_cphRoblox_rbxGroupRoleSetMembersPane_currentRoleSetID": "4725789",
            "ctl00$cphRoblox$rbxGroupRoleSetMembersPane$dlUsers_Footer$ctl02$ctl00": "",
            "ctl00$cphRoblox$rbxGroupRoleSetMembersPane$dlUsers_Footer$ctl01$HiddenInputButton": "",
            "ctl00$cphRoblox$rbxGroupRoleSetMembersPane$dlUsers_Footer$ctl01$PageTextBox": "3"
        }
        page=SESSION.post(GROUP_URL, data = postData, stream = True).text
    time.sleep(2)
```

How can I properly call the post back in ASP.NET from Python to fix this issue? As stated before, it's only printing out the same values each time.

This is the HTML Element of the button

```
<a class="pagerbtns next" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphRoblox$rbxGroupRoleSetMembersPane$dlUsers_Footer$ctl02$ctl00','')">&nbsp;</a>
```

And this is the div it is in:

```
<div id="ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxGroupRoleSetMembersPane_dlUsers_Footer_ctl01_MembersPagerPanel" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxGroupRoleSetMembersPane_dlUsers_Footer_ctl01_HiddenInputButton')">
 <div id="ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxGroupRoleSetMembersPane_dlUsers_Footer_ctl01_Div1" class="paging_wrapper">
Page <input name="ctl00$cphRoblox$rbxGroupRoleSetMembersPane$dlUsers_Footer$ctl01$PageTextBox" type="text" value="1" id="ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxGroupRoleSetMembersPane_dlUsers_Footer_ctl01_PageTextBox" class="paging_input"> of 
<div class="paging_pagenums_container">125</div>
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$cphRoblox$rbxGroupRoleSetMembersPane$dlUsers_Footer$ctl01$HiddenInputButton" value="" onclick="loading('members');" id="ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxGroupRoleSetMembersPane_dlUsers_Footer_ctl01_HiddenInputButton" class="pagerbtns translate" style="display:none;">
</div>                      
</div>
```

I was thinking of using a JS library and executing the JS `__postback` method, however, I would like to first see if this can be achieved in pure Python.

Comment: Did you make any headway with this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be achievable you just have to submit correct values on correct fields. But i assume web page you are trying parse uses asp.net web forms so it should be really time consuming to find values and such. I suggest you to look into [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html) with that you can easily call click and events on a webpage without writing so much code.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://site you are trying to parse")
driver.find_element_by_id("button").click()
//then get the data you want
```